# Pass variable as a parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, meteor

is there a way for me to pass a variable name as a string in a function?

For example, I am trying to initialize a datatable by using a function that passes in variables for the datatable's attributes. Without using a function, I would initialize the table by:

```
TabularTables.myTable = new Tabular.Table({

    name: myTable

})
```

Instead, I want to initialize it with a function like:

```
function buildTable(tableName) = {

    TabularTables.tableName = new Tabular.Table({

        name: tableName

    })

}
```

And call it as:

```
buildTable('coolTableName');
```

However, when I try this, I get the error 'Your table is missing attributes'.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bracket notation *should* work (I haven't used the plugin):

```
TabularTables[tableName] = new Tabular.Table({
```